# I need to split a 2D array at a specific row and turn them into two new 2D arrays (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this 2D array which i need to split into two 2d arrays at at specific row. I found similar answers but none in javascript.

Example of 2d array:

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[10,11,12]
[13,14,15]
[16,17,18]
[19,20,21]]
```

Desired result:

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]]

[[10,11,12]
[13,14,15]
[16,17,18]
[19,20,21]]
```

How do I do this in the easiest way? Thank you!

Comment: Your data is not well formed in JavaScript. It is missing `,` between array members. You are also not assigning the arrays to any variable. And is the desired result two separate arrays?

Comment: What's the criteria for the split? 3 rows? Numbers below 10? Something else? There is no real solution without that information

Comment: @Mathieu  It's only an example of course and not the real data, got the answer I needed down below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const input = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [10,11,12],
  [13,14,15],
  [16,17,18],
  [19,20,21]
];

const row = 3;
const output1 = input.slice(0, row);
const output2 = input.slice(row);

console.log(output1);
console.log(output2);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, so simple and elegant :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is just slicing out the correct parts manually if you know at which index to split the array.

```js
const source = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [10,11,12],
  [13,14,15],
  [16,17,18],
  [19,20,21]
];

const chunk_1 = source.slice( 0, 3 );

const chunk_2 = source.slice( 3 );

console.log( chunk_1 );

console.log( chunk_2 );
```

Is this what you are after? Or are their other constraints this ahs to follow, like not knowing in advance you have to split on the 3rd element?